# graph to continuous show the readings

Tags: java, user-interface, graph

I am reading data from serial port continually I want to show it in a graph that should shows continuous readings (Bar ,pie,Line any graph).
any Idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for some sort of real-time charting library. [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is pretty popular and is able to do real-time charts as well.

If you have the option of using the [Netbeans Platfrom](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/) take a look at this [post](http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/real-time-charts-java-desktop) which explains how to use the real-time charting API that's present in [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/).